# SQL - get distinct values and its frequency count of occurring in a group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table data as:

```
CREATE TABLE SERP (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
s_product_id INT,
search_product_result VARCHAR(255)
);


INSERT INTO SERP(s_product_id, search_product_result)
VALUES 
   (0, 'A'),
   (0, 'B'),
   (0, 'C'),
   (0, 'D'),
   (1, 'A'),
   (1, 'E'),
   (2, 'A'),
   (2, 'B'),
   (3, 'D'),
   (3, 'E'),
   (3, 'D');
```

The data set is as follows:

```
s_product_id    |    search_product_result
___________________________________________
0               |    A
0               |    B
0               |    C
0               |    D
-------------------------------------------
1               |    A
1               |    E
-------------------------------------------
2               |    A
2               |    B
-------------------------------------------
3               |    D
3               |    E
3               |    D
```

I need to list all distinct `search_product_result` values and `count` frequencies of these values occurring in `s_product_id`.

Required Output result-set:

```
DISTINCT_SEARCH_PRODUCT  |   s_product_id_frequency_count    
------------------------------------------------------------
A                        |   3
B                        |   2
C                        |   1
D                        |   2 [occurred twice in 3, but counted only once.]
E                        |   2
```

Here, `A` occurs in `three` `s_product_id` : `0, 1, 2`, `B` in `two : 0, 2`, and so on.

`D` occurred twice in the same group `3`, but is counted only once for that group.

I tried `grouping by search_product_result`, but this counts `D twice in the same group`.

```
select search_product_result, count(*) as Total from serp group by search_product_result
```

Output:

```
search_product_result  |  Total
------------------------------------
A                      |  3
B                      |  2
C                      |  1
D                      |  3  <---
B                      |  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - use `count(distinct s_product_id)`

```
select search_product_result, count(distinct s_product_id) as Total 
from serp group by search_product_result
```

Answer (score 2):

use `count(distinct()`

```
 select search_product_result, count(distinct s_product_id, search_product_result) as Total 
 from SERP 
 group by search_product_result
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=ULj1H09i1y)